# nvidia GPU available only for python2.7

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, torch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzbtm.png)

nvidia gpu is not available for python3.6, it's only available for python2.7 version.
I'm working on ubuntu, cuda 10.1, and all drivers working properly.
I also tried by creating new python environment but still gpu is available for python, not python3.
what should i do to use the gpu for runing python3 script?

please note that, tensorflow-gpu, torch is already installed and they work on python2, the only problem is that python3 doesn't use the gpu, including jupyter notebook(uses python3).
i use ssh to connect to the server, nvidia docker is already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using the nvidia docker images

1. Look for your docker image:

```
$ docker images
```

2. Run the docker image with specified IMAGE ID:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --runtime=nvidia --net=host -v /<local dir>/:/<destination dir> <IMAGE ID>

$ docker run --rm -it --runtime=nvidia --net=host -v /my_sever_dir/:/notebook 8d78dd1e1q
```

3. To access the jupyter notebook, copy the token and paste it on the browser(in the below example, provide your correct ip address and token. The port:8888 could be different if its already taken, for instance try:8889):

```
http://YOUR_IP:8888/?token=YOUR_TOKEN_FROM_STEP_2_ABOVE
```